# How do you name the shelfset in a TFS / TFVC Code Review?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Using TFS/TFVC's Code Review feature it will automatically create a shelfset for you for others to review your changes. By default it creates a shelfset named "CodeReview_xxx". If you need to update your code as part of the review process you will need to pull down & edit the shelfset by name. It would be handy if I could name the shelfset the code review is going to use instead of the auto-generated name but I don't see a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to name the shelveset that Code Review generates automatically. You could try to create the shelveset first and then request review. In this way, you can name the shelveset. Check the screenshots below:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]